# Dimensionality reduction using self-organizing map

Tags: clustering, multivariate-analysis, neural-networks, dimensionality-reduction, self-organizing-maps

Self-organizing maps are claimed to be an approach for dimensionality reduction. However, I am kind of confused about this claim.

Consider the following example, I have a data set with 200 data points and each data point is represented by a feature vector with 1000 dimensions. Assume I would like to train a map with a $1 \times 2$ grid. In other words, I will map these 200 points to two cells. Just for illustration purposes, suppose the first 100 points are mapped onto the first cell and the latter 100 points are mapped onto the second cell.  From the viewpoint of dimensionality reduction, we can say we use a 1-dimensional output space to represent the original 1000-dimensional space. But this really confuses me a lot. According to this example,  it looks to me that the first 100 points will share the same feature vector, which is just 1 in the one-dimensional space; and the latter 100 points will share the same feature vector, which is 2 in the same one-dimensional space. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: see also http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64659/using-self-organizing-maps-for-dimensionality-reduction

Comment: and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66304/how-do-soms-reduce-dimensionality-of-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your extreme example, I'd say your view is correct. You specified that you wanted a reduction to one dimension with two possible values in that dimension and that's what you got. As Wikipedia says, SOM creates a *discretized* low-dimensional representation.

Perhaps the issue is how SOM does this. Let's say you specified a 3x3 SOM, which is a 2-D grid with 9 points. The SOM algorithm embeds this 2-D grid in your 1000-D space, as Neil G points out. It then adapts the 9 points to the data in such a way as to maintain the manifold's smoothness in 1000-D space, while moving the grid points to denser (in terms of your data) areas. (It does this by propagating changes to closest SOM points in the 2-D manifold, not to neighbors in the 1000-D space.)

So, each of the 9 points in your SOM grid has a 1000-D location in 1000-D space, but after the algorithm is finished, you are considering the 9 points in the 3x3 grid itself, reducing 1000-D space to (discretized) 2-D space.

You could also look at this as a kind of clustering of your data around 9 points that are constrained in relationship to each other.

Comment: Thanks, Wayne. So SOM is quite different with other dimensionality reduction approaches, such as PCA. Say we have 200 points in 1000 dimensional space. It is like a 200*1000 matrix. Suppose we just choose the first principle component,then we can reduce the original 200*1000 matrix into 200*1 vector. On the othe side, under the SOM framework, we kind of transform 200*1000 to 9*1000 matrix. Is my understanding correct?  So SOM is more like a clustering scheme rather than a dimensionality reduction one.

Comment: @user3269: I'm not sure, but I think the 9x1000 idea doesn't account for the dual nature of the SOM. A 3x3 SOM reduces the 200x1000 matrix to a 3x3 matrix. It's like clustering, except that the 3x3 matrix defines cluster neighbors which are not necessarily neighbors in 1000-D space. Each of the 9 (3x3) SOM points corresponds to a point in 1000-D space, true, but there's more structure to a SOM than 9x1000 space. Look at the SOM graph at the top of the Wikipedia entry and you can literally see the 15x15 2D pattern, which is lost under your explanation.

Comment: @user3269: Also, when you say, "SOM is more like a clustering scheme", are you really talking about the discretized aspect of it? When you do PCA and project onto, say, the first principle component, you will "cluster" points as well, I think. It's just that with real numbers you won't end up with many points with *exactly* the same value.

Comment: Clustering is if you assign a point a discrete label. PCA does not do that, it just gives you a new vector for each point.

Comment: @bayerj: Please note the quotes around "cluster" and the previous observation which was "SOM is more like a clustering scheme".

Comment: Even with quotes, I'd argue that "PCA does clustering" is just plain wrong.

Comment: @bayerj: I'm not going to argue more. The quote does not say "PCA does clustering" or even "PCA does 'clustering'". Read in context, the statement is reasonable.

Comment: @Wayne, I still dont fully understand your explanation. So when you are done training your SOM (in the same example), where is the data that you compressed. In other words, if I wanted to access the 2D data, which was compressed from the 1000D input, where would I look?

Comment: @user1231745: I can't really answer this, since it depends entirely on what software you're using. For example, in R and using the kohonen package's som, the field is called `code`. But this will be different from another package in R, and different for other software.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that SOM reduces the dimension for visual and other analysis purposes, the mapping between the reduced space and the original space is lost. This is due the fact that your grid of 3x3 or 9 2D points are defined a priori and kept unchanged during training. What is mapped directly to the reduced space is the topological arrangement of the original space. In other words, if you pick two neighbors at the reduced space, they will be neighbors (with greater or lower distance - see umatrix) at the original space.

Answer (score 2):

A 1 by 2 SOM is not a 1-dimensional SOM, but 2-dimensional.

Your view that "... we can say we use a 1-dimensional output space to
 represent the original 1000-dimensional space." is therefore not
 right.

If you want a 1-dimensional SOM, set it at 1 by 1. Your original data
 of 200 by 1000 will then be reduced to 1 by 1000. That is, from a
 200-dimensional dataset to a 1-dimensional dataset

Answer (score 1):

No, the feature vectors $x_1$ and $x_2$ are in the 1000-dimensional space.  If you train with the same points for long enough, each feature vector approaches the Euclidean mean of its corresponding data points.